# Is there any simple pattern of slf4j usage in unit tests?

Tags: java, slf4j

I'm using JUnit4 and Hibernate3 in my project. Hibernate depends on Slf4j and thus my project includes this library as well. Now I'd like to use Slf4j in unit tests in order to log supplementary testing information. Could you please provide a short example of how my unit test should look like in order to log just one line of text? Preferably **without code duplication** in multiple tests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also like to use slf4j in my JUnit tests for my DAO class. It does help when you are creating a new test or modifying an old one. I usually leave my old logging output at debug level, and make my new logging statements at info level while I'm still actively working on the code in that method. One of my JUnit classes would look something like this:

```
package com.example.mydao;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
// other imports not shown...

public class TestMyDAO extends TestCase {

    private static final Logger logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestMyDAO.class);


    public void testA() {
        logger.debug("Logging from testA() method");
    }

    public void testB() {
        logger.debug("Logging from testB() method");
    }

    public void testThatIAmWorkingOn() {
        logger.info("Logging from my new test method at INFO level");
    }

}
```

I'm using log4j as the actual logging provider, so my `log4j.xml` configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.example.mydao" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mchange" additivity="false">
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value ="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

This gives me the info-level output from my JUnit class, as well as some useful stuff from Hibernate runtime and other libraries used with Hibernate. Adjust to your own taste.

Finally, I need to make sure that all of the following libraries are in my classpath when I execute the JUnit tests:

- `slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar`
- `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar`
- `log4j-1.2.16.jar`
- `log4j.xml` (my configuration file, shown above)
- Some version of the JUnit runtime JAR
- All the JARs normally present when running your application in production

This is what I do when using log4j. If you use a different logging implementation, then adjust accordingly. It doesn't matter if you're using a different version of slf4j, as long as the "API" and implementation JARs are the same version (mine are both 1.6.0).

Comment: And to avoid code duplication you could move the imports and `Logger` declaration to an abstract `TestCase` subclass.

Answer (score 12):

Why do you want to log things in your unit test? Unit tests should be pass/fail and should  use the testing framework to indicate that. You don't want to be reading through output to see if the test passed or failed. And if it's failing, running it in your IDE/debugger is the best way to fix it.

Comment: Because sometimes its useful to know WHY a test failed, or perhaps to print performance metrics in case you want to casually keep an eye on these.

Comment: If you want to do performance testing, do it properly and capture and graph the numbers. Casually eyeballing some numbers from a UT run is NOT the way to measure performance. And as to why a test failed, you should write your assertions so the text tells you what went wrong. At work, our product has tens of thousands of unit tests; where do you think we'd be if we had to read output from those?

Comment: I didn't say performance testing, I simply said to casually keep track of it as an example of why you might want logging in your tests. As for your work, yes we have tens of thousands of tests as well and you'd be surprised how quickly you can find the information you want related to a specific test. Besides, you won't need to read them unless you really need to, and when you really need to, its damn handy to already have the logs there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't get it. You are either interested in performance or not. If you are, spotting some numbers in the middle of a log file is not the way to keep track of what's going on. As for other "valuable" logging, the system under test is presumably doing its own logging too, so seeing the logging done by the test among any other logging must be tricky. I come back to what I originally said - unit tests should be red/green, pass/fail. And if a test fails, the failure message should tell you why.

Comment: @dty Logging during testing is important WHILE you're creating the test. Once the test is done, the log messages are obsolete, but they don't harm anyone. You will be interested to get back to them when the test fails again, say, in 1 year. Of course, in an ideal world only assertions would be enough. But we need logging very very often.

Comment: In all my (considerable!) years, I've never felt the need to add logging to a unit test. To me, this smells of the unit test being too complex. But anyway, I'm not sure how your question is different from "how do I use slf4j". I'm not sure how using it from within a unit test is relevant to the question. What's different about using it from a unit test vs using it from production code?

Comment: @dty I don't know, that's why I'm asking :) Btw I up-voted your answer since I consider it relevant to my question and it will definitely affect my future attitude to "logging in testing". Thank you.

Comment: Hehehe! Good. Making people think and challenge assumptions is just part of the service. :-)

Comment: Wow! Nearly 4 years late to the party. Welcome on board. :-/

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to switch the logging implementation to a simple implementation just for tests.

So in your pom.xml

```
    <!-- Depend on slf4j API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use SimpleLogger as the slf4j implementation in test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use log4j as the slf4j implementation during runtime (not test) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The SimpleLogger just logs everything to stderr by default and doesn't require any configuration files

Comment: SimpleLogger default log level is INFO. To change it to DEBUG, for instance, use the JVM option          
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG

Answer (score 2):

We use log4j as our output logger;

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClassHere.class);
```

slf4j should find and use log4j without issue if you configure it correctly.
To make life easy, I would use this Eclipse pattern, since you will be writing this code a fair bit:

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
${:import(org.slf4j.Logger,org.slf4j.LoggerFactory)}
```

for tests I would recommend you don't rise above INFO level and keep most things to DEBUG. If you really want to trap lots of errors intelligently then I would recommend looking into PositronLogger which is a log file appender which will silently pick up on everything down to TRACE but only dump it to file if it captures ERROR; sort of like time travelling :)

http://github.com/andreaja/PositronLogger

Comment: I need to do this `getLogger()` in every unit test inside some `@Before`-annotated method, right?

Comment: No, just the private static reference, then you can simply call log.debug("some stuff"); wherever you like.  Edit: I should clarify; the LoggerFactory.getLogger() is part of the static reference, you do not need to call it in your @Before, simply enter it as a field in your test class and it should work. A brief example: class MyTests { private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTests.class); @Test public void magic() { log.info("..."); } }

Answer (score 0):

*If using log4j 1 as the underlying slf4j implementation*

log4j doesn't log anything by default unless you,

- have a `log4j.properties` file on the classpath
- set `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.properties`. If using maven this can be done in your maven-surefire-plugin configuration.
- setup the log4j configuration programmatically, say in a @BeforeClass method

  ```
  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() {
      BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
      BasicConfigurator.configure();
  }
  ```

  This just works, however it needs to be put on *every* unit test which is a pain. So I don't recommend except if you temporarily need it to quickly get something to work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding logging while writing new tests is useful. At the same time, when the tests are being run in a CI or CD pipeline, you want logging to be disabled (or at least less verbose). Sometimes the failures are transient especially in an end-to-end run, so having relevant output on the console log of CI jobs are helpful. This article describes it very well - https://gualtierotesta.wordpress.com/2015/11/01/tutorial-logging-during-tests/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to have to setup a xml file and I didn't want to use System.out.println. Mostly I needed this for unit tests.

You can set the test logger:

```
<!-- Use SimpleLogger as the slf4j implementation in test -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Before you create your Logger set this property:  (ref: http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html other properties available other than TRACE)

```
static {
    System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel","TRACE");
}
```

Create the logger:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);


private void doSomeLogs(){
    LOGGER.trace("trace it"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you (allow) for the injection of a logger, you can use.

```
testImplementation group: 'com.portingle', name: 'slf4jtesting', version: portingleSlf4jtestingVersion
```

https://github.com/portingle/slf4jtesting

You class looks like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Inject;


public final class MyThing {

    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    MyThingTest() {
        this(LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(MyThing.class));
    }

    public MyThing(final Logger lgr) {
        if (null == lgr) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Logger is null");
        }
        this.logger = lgr;

    }
```

In your Unit Test code, you have have something like this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {

    TestLogger unitTestLogger = this.getUnitTestLogger();


    MyThing testItem = new MyThing(unitTestLogger);
   testItem.doSomethingWithLogs();
}


private TestLogger getUnitTestLogger() {
    TestLoggerFactory loggerFactory = Settings.instance()
            .enableAll() // necessary as by default only ErrorLevel is enabled
            .buildLogging();

    TestLogger returnItem = loggerFactory.getLogger(MyThingTest.class.getName());
    assertNotNull(returnItem);
    return returnItem;
}



// render nicer errors
private void assertLoggerContains(TestLogger unitTestLogger, LogLevel logLev, String expected) throws Error {
    if (!unitTestLogger.contains(logLev, expected)) {
        throw new AssertionError("expected '" + expected + "' but got '" + unitTestLogger.lines() + "'");
    }
}

// render nicer errors
private void assertLoggerNotContains(TestLogger unitTestLogger, LogLevel logLev, String expected) throws Error {
    if (unitTestLogger.contains(logLev, expected)) {
        throw new AssertionError("expected absence of '" + expected + "' but got '" + unitTestLogger.lines() + "'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `logback`:

First, you need to add the related maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you can configure your log levels via the configuration file under path:
`src/test/resources/logback.xml`

Here you can find a sample of the content of the config file:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- we can control the log level of our unit tests -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a bad smell to me.

You should always avoid manual inspection or verification for unit test.

Unit test should be automated, human intervention should only be needed if your build tools tell you that certain test failed, and the failure reason should be provided using all those verification methods (e.g. assertEquals)

Comment: Sure it does. The OP wanted to know what the code *should* look like to do this, and many of us are recommending that that code not exist. That is how it *should* be.

Comment: interesting enough, another answer from dyt is essentially saying similar thing (people should avoid logging in unit tests because of blablabla).  My answer is receiving more downvotes.  LOL

Comment: Logging during tests is often incredibly invaluable, especially when the tests fail. This of course needs to be balanced against too much logging when the tests are passing or the logs become unreadable.

Comment: @AntonPiatek That's actually wrong.  When a test fail, those pre-defined log message rarely helps in identifying the problem.  Over 99% of time, you need to look into the test, doing some debugging (which may include printing out debug messages IN THE DEBUG PROCESS).  However you shouldn't keep those log message in the test after your debug and test fixing work.  If you can think of some case that may fail and need log message inspection, write proper assertion instead.