# SLF4J log messages when running a junit test

Tags: java, testing, junit4, slf4j

When I run junit integration tests from eclipse the I do not see any log messages logged by the class under test. It might be trivial but I could not find out why?

Comment: Do you have a backend in your buildpath?  slf4j-simple is a good choice.

Comment: I do have slf4j-simple

Comment: Seems already answered or could help at least to validate your configuration:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820290/is-there-any-simple-pattern-of-slf4j-usage-in-unit-tests